# Checking if class is a type using a variable?

Tags: c#

I am trying to see if it is possible to use a System.Type in a variable in a comparison.I have the following code:

```
    internal ObservableCollection<FREQUENCY> GetFrequencies(System.Type equipmenttype)
    {
        ... 
        foreach (var incident in query)
        {

            if (typeof(equipmenttype).IsSubclassOf(typeof(incident)))
            {
                foreach (var freq in incident.FREQUENCY)
                {
                    freqs.Add(freq);
                }
            }
        }
        return freqs;
    }
```

But the variables 'tmp' and 'equipmenttype' pull the error "The type or namespace name 'tmp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I understand that usually this is used by saying typeof(MYCLASS), but I was curious if this was possible using a variable of System.Type, or if there was any way to do that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe `typeof(incident)` will compile since it's a reference, not a type.  It should be `incident.GetType()`.

Comment: Take a look at the Reflection APIs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see where is `tmp` in you code. but sure you're missing this

```
if (typeof(equipmenttype).IsSubclassOf(typeof(incident)))
```

Should be

```
if (equipmenttype.IsSubclassOf(incident.GetType()))
```

`typeof` operator is used to get the `RuntimeType` of a Type. But you already got `RuntimeType` here which is `equipmenttype`, So you don't need to use `typeof` here.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot! I had never tried anything like this before.

Answer (score 2):

Try `if (equipmenttype.IsSubclassOf(incident.GetType())`. `equipmenttype` is already a `System.Type`, and `GetType()` must be called to determine the type of an instance.